# How to lift up a button with softkeyboard and able to scroll the rest of the content behind

Tags: android

I have a `Button` which is aligned at the bottom of my screen. This `Button` lifts up when the `SoftKeyboard` is opened. The page is blank in the middle. But it has some content at the top and some right above the bottom aligned `Button`. The problem is when the `SoftKeyboard` is opened, the blank area in the middle is filled with the content in the bottom. What I want instead is, the bottom content to stay where it was and be able to scroll behind to see it.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone facing the same problem, I solved it this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <!--data binding declaration-->
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/register_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/primary_amber_200"
        tools:context=".login.view.EnterEmailActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/register_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="92dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center">
            <View
                android:id="@+id/register_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/primary_amber_100"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/register_loginBtn"
                style="@style/Button_Default_Dark_Grey"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:text="@string/next"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            style="@style/ToolBar_Basic_Light"
            android:background="@color/primary_amber_200"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_medium">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/Text_Basic_Toolbar" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/register_sv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_xlarge92">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/register_rl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/register_txtHeader"
                    style="@style/Text_Title_H1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_large"
                    android:text="@string/enter_email" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/register_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/register_txtHeader"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xlarge"
                    android:background="@color/primary_amber_100"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_small" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/register_blank"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/register_email"
                    />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/register_bottom_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
                    android:layout_below="@id/register_blank"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xxxlarge"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/register_agreetxt"
                        style="@style/Text_Body_2"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_grey_800"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:text="@string/agree" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/register_terms"
                        style="@style/Text_Button_Normal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/register_agreetxt"
                        android:text="@string/terms"
                        android:gravity="center"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/register_policy"
                        style="@style/Text_Button_Normal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/register_agreetxt"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xlarge"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/register_terms"
                        android:text="@string/policy"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/register_have_accnt"
                        style="@style/Text_Body_2"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_grey_800"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/register_terms"
                        android:text="@string/already_have_an_account"
                        android:gravity="center"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/register_login"
                        style="@style/Text_Button_Normal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/register_terms"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xlarge"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/register_have_accnt"
                        android:text="@string/login"
                        android:gravity="center"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>


        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Dont forget to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"` to your activity in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below property for your activity in android manifest. So that screen component can be accessible even after after soft keyboard opened.

```
<activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" ... >
        ...
    </activity>
```

Reference Link: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility#Respond

Comment: I did like that. But, the bottom content is lifted up as well. I want the bottom content to stay where it was.